# Would I use a Main module in a GUI driven program?

Tags: module, pseudocode

Context I am a student learning with Pseudocode currently and my final project is to be a GUI driven program where it gets the location displays it and saves it to file each time it changes. Each Module has taken care of each bit but I don't know if I need a main module or not and if I do how to go about using it.
Pseudocode here

````
MODULE Init()
    DECLARE OutputFile Append Mode Location
    DECLARE Real Lat = Location.getLatitude()
    DELCARE Real Long = Location.getLongitude()
    OPEN Location "Location.txt"
    LatitudeLabel.Text = realToString(Location.getLatitude())
    LongitudeLabel.Text = realToString(Location.getLongitude())
    WRITE Location Lat,Long
END MODULE

MODULE Location_LocationChanged()
    LatitudeLabel.Text = realToString(Location.getLatitude())
    LongitudeLabel.Text = realToString(Location.getLongitude())
    WRITE Location Lat,Long
END MODULE

MODULE exitButton_Click()
    CLOSE
END MODULE```
````

Comment: Without a main, what do you expect to use to run the rest of the code?

Comment: Ken White The book claims that each module should run themselves when their respective action is done. If I call each module with the main module what would be the point of an Init Module and Would the modules run whats inside and mess up the program doing actions it doesnt need to such as saving at a time not needed or exiting before anything has been done?